# Running test cases using lava

Tags: linux, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, linaro

I am a newbie using lava test framework.
Suppose I have some setup-ready ARM boards and running Linux or Android system, accessible by ssh/adb through network.
Is that possible only to run some test suites, for example, gcc testsuites, opencl conformance tests, without deploying the boot/kernel/rootfs images?

If I don't specify the deploy action in json, I will see following information.

```
<LAVA_DISPATCHER>2015-07-30 04:01:58 PM INFO: General Exception: No operating system deployed. Did you forget to run a deploy action?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try "Dummy_deploy" hope this is what you are looking for

```
"actions": [
        {
            "command": "dummy_deploy",
            "parameters": {
                "target_type": "ubuntu"
            }
        },
```

Target_type only matters if you need to install some dependencies, just use "ubuntu".(fedora ,oe etc are also available)

Comment: Yes. I found this "dummy_deploy" command from lava examples. It did answer my question.
Thanks!